# PHP: Limit foreach() statement?

Tags: php, foreach, limit

How can i limit a foreach() statement?
Say i only want it to run the first 2 'eaches' or something?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can either use

```
break;
```

or

```
foreach() if ($tmp++ < 2) {
}
```

(the second solution is even worse)

Answer (score 104):

There are many ways, one is to use a counter:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    /* Do stuff */
    if (++$i == 2) break;
}
```

Other way would be to slice the first 2 elements, this isn't as efficient though:

```
foreach (array_slice($arr, 0, 2) as $k => $v) {
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

You could also do something like this (basically the same as the first foreach, but with for):

```
for ($i = 0, reset($arr); list($k,$v) = each($arr) && $i < 2; $i++) {
}
```

Comment: the last one would be very slow and bad. use 1 or 2 instead.

Comment: you can also use $k as key, if($k == 2) { break; }

Answer (score 27):

you should use the [break](http://fr.php.net/break) statement

usually it's use this way

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $row){
    if(++$i > 2) break;
}
```

on the same fashion the [continue](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement exists if you need to skip some items.

Answer (score 11):

In PHP 5.5+, you can do

```
function limit($iterable, $limit) {
    foreach ($iterable as $key => $value) {
        if (!$limit--) break;
        yield $key => $value;
    }
}

foreach (limit($arr, 10) as $key => $value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

[Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) rock.

Answer (score 7):

this is best solution for me :)

```
$i=0;
foreach() if ($i < yourlimitnumber) {

$i +=1;
}
```