# get the first 6 items

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a small php code. This code get the title's of the blog items. But i have a question about this code.

How can I make it. That pick-up of last 6 titles?

```
<ul class="blog-list">
    <?php foreach ($siblings as $sibling) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($sibling->ID); ?>" data-nav-position="fade"><?php echo get_the_title($sibling->ID); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: the first or last 6 items?

Comment: The first 6 items. Thanks

Comment: Somewhat duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656969/php-limit-foreach-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take some of elements of array do not use `foreach` (see the word **each**?).

Use `for` loop instead

```
for($i = 0; $i < 6; ++$i){
  $sibling = $siblings[$i];
```

to get first 6 or

```
for($i = count($siblings); $i > count($siblings) - 6; --$i){
  $sibling = $siblings[$i];
```

to get last six (in reverse order)

**EDIT**

This won't work if array keys are not integers or have some empty ranges in it. You may then use `array_slice()` as suggested in other answer or `array_pop()` six times.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest option with not many changes in your.

```
<ul class="blog-list">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($siblings as $sibling) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($sibling->ID); ?>" data-nav-position="fade"><?php echo get_the_title($sibling->ID); ?></a></li>
    <?php if(++$i>=6) break; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

use array_slice to get last six items and then loop through it.