# convert a php for loop to foreach loop, how to iterate properly

Tags: php, foreach, each

I am trying to rewrite this for loop to remove the deprecated each()

```
for ($k = 0; (list($os_type, $os_score) = each($os_tab)) && ($k < $BBC_MAXOS); $k++) {
```

I am using a foreach loop which works except the iteration, I was wondering if there is a better way to iterate thru the loop. $BBC_MAXOS is set to 10 in the config but is not being honored.

```
foreach ($os_tab as $os_type => $os_score) {
    if ($k == 0) {
    $k < $BBC_MAXOS;
    $k++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to limit the number of times the `foreach()` is executed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656969/php-limit-foreach-statement

Comment: essentially yes. let me give this a shot see if it works thank you for the link

Comment: Are you setting the value of $k to 0 before the foreach statement?

Comment: Yes I  set  $k=0; just before the loop.. I added break to the condition and actually fixed the greater than sign and it worked                                                                          
    ` if ($k == 0) {
    $k > $BBC_MAXOS break;
    $k++;
    } `